# SFRestAPI.h in the Objective-C SDK appears to be missing methods

Tags: files, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I'm building a Salesforce integration in an existing iOS app. As part of the integration workflow, I need to allow a user to upload a PDF to a specific opportunity. When the upload is complete, it should show up here in the Salesforce interface:

[image: The files section of an Opportunity in Salesforce Classic]

I searched the Mobile SDK documentation for information about files and file uploading and I [found the relevant section.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/files_ios.htm) From there I was able to find a separate page with the [Files API documentation](http://forcedotcom.github.io/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/Documentation/SalesforceSDKCore/html/Classes/SFRestAPI.html).

The issue I have is two fold. First, the relevant factory method on SFRestAPI to return the appropriate SFRestRequest appears to be this one:

```
– requestForUploadFile:name:description:mimeType:apiVersion:
```

However, none of the "Files" methods appear to exist in SFRestAPI.h.

Second, even if I were to use this method to create the SFRestRequest, it's unclear to me how to relate this upload of a file to a specific Opportunity.

Am I going about this the right way? Has something been recently deprecated or moved that I haven't discovered yet? Should I be looking elsewhere for Files API documentation in addition to the Mobile SDK?

Thanks!

[Edit: I did a quick pod update and moved from 7.2.0 to 7.3.0 on all of my included SalesforceSDK pods. Issue still persists.]